# replace 220v transformer into a 110v transformer with same specs

Tags: transformer, guitar-amplifier

I am trying to convert my European 220V VOX AD50VT guitar amplifier into 110V to use it in the USA. I plugged it to 110V and it does not work, there's just the master light that comes up but it appears very weak.

From my research, it seems that it boils down to swapping the existing 220V transformer for the same in 110V.
From the amplifier documentation, I have the part number that I need:

[image]

However, the transformer has been discontinued:
See https://www.partsisparts.net/catalog/vox-ad50vt-power-transformer-v904050029

[image]

I am looking for a similar transformer but struggle with what I should order.
The schematic I found shows the following:

See https://bespin.federalproductions.com/mycloud/Organ%20Documents/Owners%20and%20Service%20Manuals/Korg/AD50VT1.pdf

[image]
[image]

I also used my multimeter to check the voltage on each winding, here there:

[image]

This is what I found online which looks like the closest to what I need to purchase:

[image]

I'm hoping someone can help me find the correct transformer that I should buy, thank you.

Comment: Asking what to buy and from where is off-topic. The transformer is complex to replace because it has so many secondaries. It might be simpler to buy a product intended for using 220V devices in 110V country, a step-up transformer, and buy a ready made product, not just the transformer.

Answer (score 1):

Just get an external 110 to 220 V transformer and call it a day.